# How to generate a SAS code by running another SAS code

Tags: sas, auto-generate

I am trying to create a simple SAS program which looks like below,

```
student_id = 123;
class_id   = 123;
name       = 'John';
```

How can I use another SAS code to automatically generate a SAS program contains as simple contents as shown above?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: exactly, what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

Any SAS Macro is doing exactly that, generating code.

```
%macro run_my_code;
student_id = 123;
class_id   = 123;
name       = 'John';
%mend run_my_code;

%run_my_code;
```

If you want something more specific than that, though, you're going to have to give a more specific question.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, I am actually trying to create a program A that assigns value to variables such as 'student_id', 'class_id' and 'name' and put the result in another program B as

Comment: student_id = 123;
class_id   = 123;
name       = 'John'; Then I have program C to %include program B into it by the name of program B.